# Request.Url.Segments[3] not working with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis

`Request.Url.Segments[3]` returns pagename. at my demo server have `IIS6` and its working fine but at my live server had installed `IIS7` and `Request.Url.Segments[3]` does not return page name it gives an error.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the version of IIS. Most likely, you have a different setup for the site.

For example, on dev, by default on Visual Studio <kbd>F5</kbd> debug, the site runs at:

```
http://localhost:1234/sitename/folder/page.aspx
                     |\_______/\_____/\_______/
                     0    1       2       3
```

On test/production, you may not have the first folder:

```
http://sitename.corpo.com/folder/page.aspx
                         |\_____/\_______/
                         0   1      2
```

There are better ways of getting the last element of an array dynamically, even without knowing its length. Try using:

```
Request.Url.Segments.Last()
```

Or, without linq,

```
Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1]
```

If you are not looking for the last element, you may have to come up with a better way of specifying what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The value for each item in `.Segments` is entirely dependent on the Url, which is dictated by how the site is set up in IIS.

For instance, having your site at the root of the webserver will give different reseults to having the site under a virtual root.

In the url http://myserver/mypage.aspx, the page is at item index 1.
In the url http://myserver/myvirtualroot/mypage.aspx, the page is at item index 2.

You can demostrate this for yourself as follows:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://myserver/mypage.aspx");
for (var i = 0; i < uri.Segments.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Segments[{0}]: {1}",i,  uri.Segments[i]);
}
```

This gives:

```
Segments[0]: /
Segments[1]: mypage.aspx
```

now try it again for

```
var uri2 = new Uri("http://myserver/myvirtualroot/mypage.aspx");
```

this time you'll get:

```
Segments[0]: /
Segments[1]: myvirtualroot/
Segments[2]: mypage.aspx
```

The point is that you can't reliably say "item index 3 is the page" unless you know that the actual site url (and hence its configuration in IIS) is the same across environments. (Even then. it is not a particularly nice way of doing it as it is so brittle to changes)

As Kobi points out, simply using uri.Segments.Last() will get you the last segment (without the querystring if there is one) which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Went a little too far there - the `Segments` array will not include the query either way, you don't have to search for it. That's exactly why the `Uri` class is so useful - it deals successfully with real URIs. See the examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx

Comment: You're right - no need to provide the extension method at all. I started off with .PathAndQuery and did a split, which *did* need this. Then I switched to .Segments and didn't re-run the code. My bad - thank you for the spot - I'll edit.